# XmlNode RemoveAll() nullifies reference of nodes held by other variables

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to remove all child nodes from root apart from the one that is needed to be present and here is what i wrote

```
                XmlNode root = XmlTemplate.DocumentElement;

                string targetPrefix = root.Prefix;
                var xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlTemplate.NameTable);
                xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace(root.Prefix, root.NamespaceURI);
                XmlNodeList nodeList = null;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetPrefix))
                {
                    nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::" + targetPrefix + ":fields", xmlNamespaceManager);
                }
                else
                {
                    nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::fields");
                }
```

As expected I am able to get the required node in nodeList. i can the node in debug mode. Confusion starts when below code statements run

```
root.RemoveAll();
root.AppendChild(nodeList[0]);
```

as per my understanding the child node is still referenced in the nodeList hence object would have not got garbage collected but after root.RemoveAll() executes nodeList becomes empty.

`root.innexText ="";` also does same

is there anything different with XML methods? which concept have i misunderstood...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation on the `SelectNodes` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> The XmlNodeList object returned by this method will be valid while the underlying document remains unchanged. If the underlying document changes, unexpected results may be returned (no exception will be thrown).

Therefore, it seems that the resulting [`XmlNodeList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in some way coupled to the underlying Xml document. Once the document has been changed by your call to [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removeall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), no particular behaviour of the `XmlNodeList` is guaranteed.

Therefore, in your case, it should be the safest to copy the contents of the node list before removing the nodes from your document:

```
var nodes = nodeList.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray();
```

This uses some extension methods from the [`System.Linq.Enumerable` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to copy the contents of the `XmlNodeList` into a new array (that is independent of the Xml document).